# Want to make Wd template to be dynamic

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have the following macro, and I want the Wd template (Template fisa de esantionare.dotm) to make it dynamic, run by different users. Thanks

Modyfi this line of code:
 .Documents.Add "C:\Users\stefan.georgescu\Desktop\Template fisa de esantionare.dotm"

```
Sub ExportExcelDataToWordDocument()

    'Dim wdExcelApp As Application               'Excel is the default library (optional)
    Dim wdWordApp As Word.Application            'Word app
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim LastRow As Long

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Creating a new instance of Word
    Set wdWordApp = New Word.Application 'instantiate a new instance of Word 2010


    With wdWordApp

        ' Making Word Visible on the screen
        .Visible = True             'iff false, document is invisible.

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' create a new Word Document based on the specified template
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        .Documents.Add "C:\Users\stefan.georgescu\Desktop\Template fisa de esantionare.dotm"

        'as before, copy the whole table from sheet to clipboard.
        Set WB = ThisWorkbook
        With WB.Sheets("GestiuneSSC")
        LastRow = .Range("A:F").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Range("A1", "F" & LastRow).Select
        Selection.Copy
        wdWordApp.Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="bookmark1" ' -1 means "wdgotobookmark"
        wdWordApp.Selection.Paste      'paste from the clipboard to the Word Doc.

        End With

        '****************
                'as before, copy the whole table from sheet to clipboard.
        Sheets("AlimATM").Select
        Set WB = ThisWorkbook
        With WB.Sheets("AlimATM")
        LastRow = .Range("A:F").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Range("A1", "F" & LastRow).Select
        Selection.Copy
        wdWordApp.Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="bookmark2" ' -1 means "wdgotobookmark"
        wdWordApp.Selection.Paste      'paste from the clipboard to the Word Doc.

        End With

  '****************
                'as before, copy the whole table from sheet to clipboard.
        Sheets("DepRidAngajati").Select
        Set WB = ThisWorkbook
        With WB.Sheets("DepRidAngajati")
        LastRow = .Range("A:F").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        Range("A1", "F" & LastRow).Select
        Selection.Copy
        wdWordApp.Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="bookmark3" ' -1 means "wdgotobookmark"
        wdWordApp.Selection.Paste      'paste from the clipboard to the Word Doc.

        End With

        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' Save WORD Document
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Dim TheFileName As String
        TheFileName = "C:\Users\stefan.georgescu\Desktop\Fisa de esantionare.docx"

        '......................................
        'Autofit tables in Wdoc
        Dim t As Table
        For Each t In ActiveDocument.Tables
        t.AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitContent
        Next
        '.......................................

        '(SaveAs is for Office 2003 and earlier - deprecated)
        .ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 TheFileName
            'replaces existing .doc iff exists


        ' Close Documents and Quit Word
        .ActiveDocument.Close 'close .DOCx
        .Quit 'exit Word
    End With

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'MEMORY CLEANUP
    Set wdWordApp = Nothing 'garbage collection
    'Set wdExcelApp = Nothing 'OPTIONAL


End Sub
```

Comment: The "Template fisa de esantionare.dotm" will be saved locally on each user desktop.

Comment: why would you save a template to the user's desktop - which could result in different users using different versions of the template - instead of having a single template stored somewhere all users can access?

Comment: Hi, macroprod. Don't know, it was just an idea :)

Comment: All users are already used to this way of working, with an unchanged template saved on desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should put templates in a common location all users can access instead of putting separate copies on the users' desktops. That said, you could use:

```
.Documents.Add "C:\Users\" & Environ("Username") & "\Desktop\Template fisa de esantionare.dotm"
```

Comment: If I want to make this line also dynamic?                                                                        ' Save WORD Document
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Dim TheFileName As String
        TheFileName = "C:\Users\stefan.georgescu\Desktop\Fisa de esantionare.docx"

Comment: Done! Thank you!